# How may we obtain a version of a letter which tolerates math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to use the German `\ss`, and quite often in mathematical contexts.

How may I have the letter so that I can write `$\ss$`, without receiving error messages?

Comment: Please get into the habit of adding a small but compileable test document to your questions. Also are you sure that your readers will be able to distinguish ß from a normal `\beta` as it is often used in math?

Comment: It is also a bad idea to delete duplicates like your biblatex question yesterday. Better edit the posts to fix problems like a missing minimal working example. If you delete too many of your not so well-received questions, you might get an automatic question ban.

Comment: With more than 100 question, you still might want to take a look at [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) and [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz \ss is as compilable as a, in text mode. Mathematicians will not confound \ss and \beta.

Comment: How many mathematicians would ever use `\ss` in math mode? I've never seen that even once.

Comment: @daleif It is to name a \sstabilising ordinal, so it has some mnemotechnical value.

Comment: there is no mathematical ß in unicode, quite differently to a. Apart from this: define a new command: `\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathss}{\mathord}{operators}{25}` (assuming pdftex).

Comment: Depends on the intention `\text{\ss}` may be semantically better. But if you do intend to use it as a math symbol like `a` then one way is to copy the symbol somewhere then use `\TextOrMath` or something.

Comment: Please provide an example of how you want to use it.  Without such an example, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @barbarabeeton https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohgata3i5rul21o/Screen%20Shot%202023-05-09%20at%2016.10.56.pdf?dl=0

Comment: At this point I solved the problem, thanks to the suggestion by @UlrikeFischer. I would welcome an answer.